# Selecting certain values that contain every number but not only one

Tags: sql, oracle

Allow me to preface this by saying that I am fairly new to sql, and I'm sure there is an easy way to do this that I'm not understanding.

Lets say we have a table:

```
X | Y
2 | 2
3 | 1
3 | 3
3 | 2
```

I am trying to find values of y such that x contains both 2 and 3.

Basically, y = 2 is the only value that satisfies this.

EDIT: I know that in relational algebra this is trivial with division

Comment: always try include your rdbms version as a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably try this:

```
select y
from test 
where x in (2,3) 
group by y 
having count(*) = 2;
```

EDIT: Notice a good recommendation by Juan. In case your data contains X=2 and Y=2, a better way of writing the query would be this:

```
select y
from test 
where x in (2,3) 
group by y 
having count(distinct x) = 2;
```

Comment: what if `Y = (2,2)`, maybe `count(distinct x)`

Comment: Great point, @JuanCarlosOropeza. In case X=2 and Y=2, count(distinct x) would be appropriate. I'll add an edit for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

using a conditional `SUM`. If any group of `Y` contain `2` sum will be greater than 0, same with `3`

```
 SELECT Y
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY Y
 HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN X = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    and SUM(CASE WHEN X = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`INTERSECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm):

```
SELECT Y
FROM YourTable
WHERE X = 2

INTERSECT

SELECT Y
FROM YourTable
WHERE X = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the analytic **LAG()** function.

```
SELECT y
FROM
  ( SELECT x, 
           y, 
           lag(x) OVER(PARTITION BY y ORDER BY x) x_lag FROM your_table WHERE x IN (2, 3)
  )
WHERE x_lag = x - 1;
```

**Working demo:**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 2 X, 2 Y FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 3 X, 1 Y FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3 X, 3 Y FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 3 X, 2 Y FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT y
  8  FROM
  9    ( SELECT x,
 10     y,
 11     lag(x) OVER(PARTITION BY y ORDER BY x) x_lag FROM data WHERE x IN (2, 3)
 12    )
 13  WHERE x_lag = x - 1;

         Y
----------
         2
```